# Java regular expression finding number

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse log using regex. Unfortunately I' stacked on following string.
Trying to find line beginning with time

for example:

```
String p="11:33:00.0   2000           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ...";
```

I have following code:

```
public class Test {


public static void main(String[] args) {
  String p="11:33:00.0   2000           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ...";
  Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^\\d\\d\\:\\d\\d*");
  Matcher m = pat.matcher(p);
  if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.start());
    System.out.println(p.substring(m.start()));
  }

}
}
```

this code prints nothing even if I tried just '^\d\d'.

if I'm correct 
'^' stands for line beginning
'\d' for any digit

I also tried to replace '^' with '\A'
If i change pattern to

```
pat = Pattern.compile("\\d\\d");
```

it returns position at 6.
Can somebody tell me why the first code is not working?:)

THX

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the group index 0 inside the if block, so that it would print the matched characters.

```
String p="11:33:00.0   2000           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ....... #           0.0     ...";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^\\d\\d\\:\\d\\d*");
Matcher m = pat.matcher(p);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
11:33
```

Comment: @sala84 what's your expected output?

Comment: syso is just check, my problem is I can't get into if, with current code and I don't know why I have no output. You changed nothing and you still have print:)

Comment: the above code works for me. i just added this `System.out.println(m.group(0));` line only.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer your example Test.main worked fine, maybe it's dependant on JVM implementation. I think if you open then you also need to close regex with question mark:

```
"^\\d\\d?"
```